# Referencing Action Parameters from ExceptionLogger

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm wanting to make use of the new method for globally logging errors. I've written a class that inherits `ExceptionLogger` and overrides the `Log()` method. Then registered it as a replacement.

```
public class TraceExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public async override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        //  This is always empty string
        var content = await context.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        //  This is almost always null
        var actionContext = context.ExceptionContext.ActionContext;
    }
}
```

I can dig through the `ExceptionLoggerContext` object's properties to get pretty much everything I need, EXCEPT for action parameters. There is indeed an `ActionContext` property but I've only seen it null and [this wiki page](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Global%20Error%20Handling) states that `ActionContext` and `ControllerContext` will almost always be null.

Also, I can't get the content stream because its stream is already read before it gets to my logger. So there's no way for me to get any posted json from the request's content.

Is there maybe a way to get the posted data from `HttpContext.Current` or in some other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok it looks like I can get the body text from HttpContext by reading InputStream on the Request object like this:

```
string bodyText = string.Empty;

using (var sr = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
{
    sr.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    bodyText = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

This code has been successful me so far for getting my posted json data.

Comment: YOU SAVED MY ASS! I was about to kill myself. It was super frustrating not being able to log request content.

Comment: @StefanVasiljevic I'm so glad that it helped and that I have saved your life. I think that is the first time my code has ever done that haha. Cheers!

Comment: @jlafay ..and it won't be the last! Nov 2017, still saving lives!

Comment: @jlafay This might sound dumb, but how do you get from ExceptionLoggerContext to HttpContext

Comment: @Achilles, that is not a dumb question at all. That's a very valid inquiry. HttpContext and HttpContext.Current are static. So you can access the current context at any given time.

Comment: You are seriously awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Here's action parameters for future reference

```
public class HomeController : ApiController {
    public string Get(string id, [FromHeader] Whoever whoever) {

    public string Post(Whatever whatever) {


var args = ((ApiController) context.ExceptionContext
           .ControllerContext.Controller)).ActionContext.ActionArguments

if (args.ContainsKey("whatever")) {
   var whatever = (Whatever)args["whatever"];
```