# Proper way to retrieve the Request.Content from global error handler

Tags: error-handling, asp.net-web-api2

I have register a global exception handler, and it fires and contains all of the information I need with the exception of the Request.Content which is always empty...  I need the values that were passed in when I am debugging...

```
Public class MyExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
    {
        public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
        {

            try
            {
                 ... other code

            var methodName = context.Request.Method.ToString();
            var errorUri = context.Request.RequestUri.ToString();
            var errorMessage = context.Exception.Message;
            var errorStackTrace = context.Exception.StackTrace.ToString();

            var payload = context.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            .....  other code  

            }

       }
   }
```

What is the proper way to retrieve the Request.Content from global error handler ? In the code above the Content property has already been read by the model binders and as such is always empty.

How can I consistently get the posted body from an exception ?

Should I retrieve and save the posted body in a custom MessageHandler ?

Thanks
Greg

Answer (score 1):

In experimenting with reading the buffer of the request.Content in a custom message handler.. It appears that if I read it with this code:

```
var payload = context.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

and do NOTHING with it...  The buffer will not be emptied when the model binders read it, because its always there in my exception logger now... I don't know if this is by design or what but its exasperating !

Comment: Just noticed the same behavior in my `ExceptionLogger`. Not sure if it is a bug or a feature…

Comment: For others looking for the actual answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22972220/632495