# What is the best practice to log request body on failed requests in Application Insights?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights

What is the best way to log the HTTP request body when a request fails?

I'm logging unhandled exceptions by overriding the Exception logger:

```
 public class AiExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        if (context != null && context.Exception != null)
        {
            ExceptionTelemetry telemetry = new ExceptionTelemetry(context.Exception);

            // the requestBody is always empty because the stream is non-rewinadable?
            string requestBody = context.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            telemetry.Properties.Add("Request Body", requestBody);

            Logger.LogException(telemetry);
        }
        base.Log(context);
    }
}
```

With the above code, the request content is always empty. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22972220/3646421), but that throws an unsupported method exception due to calling GetBufferlessInputStream. So that doesn't work either.

I could log all request content using a DelegatingHandler, but I'd only like to log the request body on failed requests caused by unhandled exceptions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> With the above code, the request content is always empty.

You could get the request stream using ReadAsStreamAsync method and reset the position of this stream. After that, you can read the content from this steam using StreamReader. Code below is for your reference. I tested it and it worked fine on my side.

```
ExceptionTelemetry telemetry = new ExceptionTelemetry(context.Exception);

//Get request stream and reset the position of this stream
Stream requestBodyStream = context.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
requestBodyStream.Position = 0;
string requestBody = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(requestBodyStream))
{
    requestBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
telemetry.Properties.Add("Request Body", requestBody);
```

Comment: I accepted your answer even though I used Mitch Stewart's CopyTo approach. But since his code is incomplete and needs modifications to work, I couldn't mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: @ErtayShashko I'm not sure why this is the accepted answer since it doesn't work. You cannot reset the position.

Comment: @Phill, If you can't reset the position of requestBodyStream in your environment, You could copy it to a MemoryStream and reset the position of MemoryStream. Then we can read the data from MemoryStream.  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
requestBodyStream.CopyTo(ms);
ms.Position = 0;

Comment: @Amor-MSFT - it also does not work. It's not my environment. It's Web API 2. Anyway this answer solved the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/33531912/456813

Comment: The code which I posted was tested and working fine on my ASP.NET MVC project. Thanks for pointing out the solution for ASP.NET Web API project.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You can't reset the Position property the same way you can with Streams. Instead, copy the content and read the copy.

```
if (context != null && context.Exception != null)
{
    HttpContent requestContent = new HttpContent();
    request.Content.CopyToAsync(requestContent);
    ExceptionTelemetry telemetry = new ExceptionTelemetry(context.Exception);

    // the requestBody is always empty because the stream is non-rewinadable?
    string requestBody = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    telemetry.Properties.Add("Request Body", requestBody);

    Logger.LogException(context.Exception);
}
```

Comment: HttpContent is an abstract class, and also CopyTo takes in a Stream :) You'll need to edit your answer. I'll try to see if it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to Amor - MSFT's answer using `CopyTo`

```
public class AiExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public  override async void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        if (context != null && context.Exception != null)
        {
            ExceptionTelemetry telemetry = new ExceptionTelemetry(context.Exception);

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await context.Request.Content.CopyToAsync(ms);
                var requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                telemetry.Properties.Add("Request Body", requestBody);
            }


            Logger.LogException(telemetry);
        }
        base.Log(context);
    }
}
```